# Implement Youtube player fragment inside other fragment

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

How to implement Youtube player fragment inside other fragment? Is there any way by which I can implement youtube API inside fragment?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: how to implement youtube api inside fragment......any example that can i understand..i have implement in inside activity not in fragment.....

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code that you can show us so that we can help you?

Comment: i want to try to implement youtube player api inside fragment.....

Comment: If you're just looking for a general example you can check [this repository](https://github.com/Glurt/EdenYouTube).